# Scalable "Evaluated at" bar

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'd like to create a macro of some sort which produces a vertical bar `|` which scales with the height of the object it's referred to. Using the physics package this works as follows:

```
\eval{\pdv{f}{x}}_y
```

However I'd like to use something like:

```
\pdv{f}{x}\eval|_x
\pdv{f}{x}\eval_x
\pdv{f}{x}\eval{x}
```

This is because when I'm writing it comes more natural to write the vertical bar after the derivative. I may use $\bigg|$ or $\Bigg|$ since most of my expressions have similar heights but I'd like to know if there's some way to make this work so that it scales.

Comment: I usually just use an explicit `\left. f(x) \right\rvert_{x=x_0}` for this. You could wrap this in a macro if necessary, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of having a macro `\eval{...}` is (I guess) to ensure the scaling (which I don't like in general). It would be possible to patch `\pdv` such that it saves the height of the whole construct in a length register which is later used to build the par, but I don't like and I don't use the `physics` package. Furthermore, automatic scaling is in general very dangerous as you see in the following example

```
\[
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_x
\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{f}}{\partial x}\right|_x
\]
```

[image]

I believe there is no doubt that the second expression looks appalling.

Honestly, I see no big difference in having something which works as

```
\frac{dy}{dx}\eval_x
```

over the more direct

```
\frac{dy}{dx}\biggr|_x
```

except sparing two keystrokes and making the code IMO less legible (though the latter comment might depend on how my eyes and brain parse LaTeX math). But if your `\eval` almost always have the same height (say `\bigg`) then you could define something like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\eval}[1][\bigg]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \def\next{\mathclose|}%
   \else
      \def\next{\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1r\endcsname|}%
   \fi
   \next
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\eval_x \quad
a\eval[\big]_x \quad
a\eval[]_x \quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\eval[\Bigg]_x^y
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

By default `\bigg` is used; different sizes can be given as optional parameter.

Comment: This is close enough to what I was looking for, thanks.